# How to get notified before static variables are finalized

Tags: c#, singleton, dispose, lazy-evaluation

When can i cleanup objects stored in static variables in C#?

I have a static variable that is [lazily initialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx):

```
public class Sqm
{
    private static Lazy<Sqm> _default = new Lazy<Sqm>();

    public static Sqm Default { get { return _default.Value; } }
}
```

**Note**: That i've just changed `Foo` to be a `static` class. It doesn't change the question in any way if `Foo` is static or not. But some people are convinced that there is no way that an instance of `Sqm` could be constructed without first constructing an instance of `Foo`. Even if i *did* create a `Foo` object; even if i created 100 of them, it wouldn't help me solve the problem (of when to *"cleanup"* a static member).

**Sample usage**

```
Foo.Default.TimerStart("SaveQuestion");
//...snip...
Foo.Default.TimerStop("SaveQuestion");
```

Now, my `Sqm` class implements a method that must be called when the object is no longer needed, and needs to clean itself up (save state to filing system, release locks, etc). This method **must** be called before the garbage collectors runs (i.e. before my object's finalizer is called):

```
public class Sqm
{
   var values = new List<String>();         
   Boolean shutdown = false;

   protected void Cleanup(ICollection stuff)
   {
      WebRequest http = new HttpWebRequest();
      http.Open("POST", "https://stackoverflow.com/SubmitUsageTelemetry");
      http.PostBody = stuff;
      http.Send();
   }

   public void Shutdown()
   { 
      if (!alreadyShutdown)
      {
         Cleanup(values);
         alreadyShutdown = true;
      }
   }
}
```

When, and where, can i call my `Shutdown()` method?

**Note**: I don't want the developer who *uses* the `Sqm` class to have to worry about calling `Shutdown`. That's not his job. In other language environments he would not have to.

The `Lazy<T>` class does not seem to call `Dispose` on the `Value` it lazily owns. So i cannot hook the `IDisposable` pattern - and use that as the time to call `Shutdown`. I need to call `Shutdown` myself.

But when?

It's a `static` variable, it exists once for the life of the application/domain/appdomain/apartment.

## Yes, the finalizer is the wrong time

Some people do understand, and some people don't, that trying to upload my data during a `finalizer` is ***wrong***.

```
///WRONG: Don't do this!
~Sqm
{
   Shutdown(_values); //<-- BAD! _values might already have been finalized by the GC!
}
```

Why is it wrong? Because `values` might not be there anymore. You don't control what objects are finalized in what order. It is entirely possible that `values` was finalized before the containing `Sqm`.

## What about dispose?

The `IDisposable` interface, and the `Dispose()` method is a *convention*. There is nothing that dictates that if my object implements a `Dispose()` method that it will ever be called. In fact, i *could* go ahead and implement it:

```
public class Sqm : IDisposable
{
   var values = new List<String>();         
   Boolean alreadyDiposed = false;

   protected void Cleanup(ICollection stuff)
   {
      WebRequest http = new HttpWebRequest();
      http.Open("POST", "https://stackoverflow.com/SubmitUsageTelemetry");
      http.PostBody = stuff;
      http.Send();
   }

   public void Dispose()
   { 
      if (!alreadyDiposed)
      {
         Cleanup(values);
         alreadyDiposed = true;
      }
   }
}
```

To the person actually reading the question, you might notice that i didn't actually change anything. The only thing i did was to change the name of a method from *Shutdown* to *Dispose*. The Dispose pattern is simply a convention. i still have the problem: when can i call `Dispose`?

## Well you should call dispose from your finalizer

Calling `Dispose` from my finalizer is just as incorrect as calling `Shutdown` from my finalizer (they are identically wrong):

```
public class Sqm : IDisposable
{
   var values = new List<String>();         
   Boolean alreadyDiposed = false;

   protected void Cleanup(ICollection stuff)
   {
      WebRequest http = new HttpWebRequest();
      http.Open("POST", "https://stackoverflow.com/SubmitUsageTelemetry");
      http.PostBody = stuff;
      http.Send();
   }

   public void Dispose()
   { 
      if (!alreadyDiposed)
      {
         Cleanup(_values); // <--BUG: _values might already have been finalized by the GC!
         alreadyDiposed = true;
      }
   }

   ~Sqm
   {
      Dispose();
   }
}
```

Because, again, `values` might not be there anymore. For completeness, we can return to the full original correct code:

```
public class Sqm : IDisposable
{
   var values = new List<String>();         
   Boolean alreadyDiposed = false;

   protected void Cleanup(ICollection stuff)
   {
      WebRequest http = new HttpWebRequest();
      http.Open("POST", "https://stackoverflow.com/SubmitUsageTelemetry");
      http.PostBody = stuff;
      http.Send();
   }

   protected void Dispose(Boolean itIsSafeToAlsoAccessManagedResources)
   { 
      if (!alreadyDiposed)
      {
         if (itIsSafeToAlsoAccessManagedResources)
            Cleanup(values);
         alreadyDiposed = true;
      }
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      this.Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }

   ~Sqm
   {
      Dispose(false); //false ==> it is not safe to access values
   }
}
```

i've come full circle. i have an object which i need to *"cleanup"* before the application domain shuts down. Something inside my object needs to be notified when it can call `Cleanup`.

## Make the developer call it

No.

i'm migrating existing concepts from another language into C#. If a developer happens to use the global singleton instance:

```
Foo.Sqm.TimerStart();
```

then the `Sqm` class is lazy initialized. In a (native) application, the reference to the object is held. During (native) application shutdown, the variable holding the interface pointer is set to `null`, and the singleton object's `destructor` is called, and it can clean itself up.

Nobody should ever have to call anything. Not `Cleanup`, not `Shutdown`, not `Dispose`. Shutdown should happen automatically by the infrastructure.

What is the C# equivalent of *i see myself going away, clean myself up*?

It's complicated by the fact that if you let the garbage collector collect the object: it's too late. The internal state objects i want to persist are likely already finalized.

## It would be easy if from ASP.net

If i could guarantee that my class were being used from ASP.net, i could ask the `HostingEnvironment` to notify before the domain shuts down by registering my object with it:

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);
```

And implement the the `Stop` method:

```
public class Sqm : IDisposable, IRegisteredObject
{
   var values = new List<String>();         
   Boolean alreadyDiposed = false;

   protected void Cleanup(ICollection stuff)
   {
      WebRequest http = new HttpWebRequest();
      http.Open("POST", "https://stackoverflow.com/SubmitUsageTelemetry");
      http.PostBody = stuff;
      http.Send();
   }

   protected void Dispose(Boolean itIsSafeToAlsoAccessManagedResources)
   { 
      if (!alreadyDiposed)
      {
         if (itIsSafeToAlsoAccessManagedResources)
            Cleanup(values);
         alreadyDiposed = true;
      }
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      this.Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }

   Sqm
   {
      //Register ourself with the ASP.net hosting environment,
      //so we can be notified with the application is shutting down
      HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this); //asp.net will call Stop() when it's time to cleanup
   }

   ~Sqm
   {
      Dispose(false); //false ==> it is not safe to access values
   }

   // IRegisteredObject
   protected void Stop(Boolean immediate)
   {
      if (immediate) 
      {
         //i took too long to shut down; the rug is being pulled out from under me.
         //i had my chance. Oh well.
         return;
      }

      Cleanup(); //or Dispose(), both good
   }
}
```

Except my class doesn't know if i'll be called from **ASP.net**, or from **WinForms**, or from **WPF**, or a console application, or shell extension.

**Edit**: People seem to be confused by [what the `IDisposable` pattern exists for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/12597). Removed references to `Dispose` in order to remove the confusion.

**Edit 2**: People seem to be demanding full, detailed, example code before they will answer the question. Personally i think the question already contains too much example code, as it doesn't serve to help ask the question.

And now that i've added ***sooo*** much code, the question has been lost. People refuse to answer a question until the question has been justified. Now that it's been justified, nobody will read it.

## It's like diagnostics

It's like the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` class. People call it when they want:

```
Trace.WriteLine("Column sort: {0} ms", sortTimeInMs);
```

and never have to think of it again.

## And then desperation sets in

i was even desperate enough, that i considered hiding my object behind an COM `IUnknown` interface, which is reference counted

```
public class Sqm : IUnknown
{
   IUnknown _default = new Lazy<Sqm>();
}
```

And then hopefully i could *trick* the CLR into decrementing the reference count on my interface. When my reference count becomes zero, i know everything is shutting down.

The downside of that is that i cannot make it work.

Comment: It's a static variable. It belongs to the class and will only get destroyed when Foo is destroyed

Comment: @Nick `Foo` can (and likely never will) be created; so i won't know when it's destroyed.

Comment: If `Foo` is created then It will be destroyed on Unloading AppDomain only

Comment: @SriramSakthivel What happens if `Foo` is never created (as it likely never will be). Unless you meant *If `Sqm` is created then it will be destroyed on Unloading AppDomain only*. In which case, how can my `Sqm` object be notified when the AppDomain is unloaded?

Comment: If Foo is never created then `Sqm` will also never be created right? what is your question? If you're talking about default `AppDomain` then there is no way to get notification, If you're creating your own `AppDomain` then you can subscribe for [DomainUnload event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload.aspx)

Comment: FYI Default `AppDomain` will unload when your process is exits. If your process exits gracefully and if it is a `WinForm App` you could use `Application.ApplicationExit` event. Is there a reason why you want to do this and what kind of cleanup?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel `Sqm` can be created even if an instance of `Foo` is never created. Notice in the **Sample Usage** above that nobody ever creates a `new` instance of `Foo`, but **does** create an instance of `Sqm`.

Comment: Ah, yes it does creates `sqm`. So you're using ConsoleApp or Winform?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Console app, WinForms, ASP.net, COM-callable wrapper. It doesn't matter. My constructed object should be able to get notified whenever the appdomain it lives is is about to be shutdown.

Comment: @IanBoyd: It does matter, because those different project types have different life-cycles. Some give more notification of shutdown than others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had asked this question four times, if four different ways. Phrasing each one slightly different; trying to solve the problem from a different direction. Eventually it was [M.A. Hanin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033100/unload-event-for-the-default-application-domain) that pointed me at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673332/net-code-execution-at-normal-process-exit/16678779#16678779) that solved the problem.

The issue is that there is no single way to know when the domain is shutting down. The best you can do is try to catch various kinds of events that cover you 100% (rounded to the nearest percentage) of the time.

If the code is in some domain *besides* the default, then use the `DomainUnload` event. Unfortunately the **default** AppDomain doesn't raise a `DomainUnload` event. So then we catch `ProcessExit`:

```
class InternalSqm 
{
   //constructor
   public InternalSqm ()
   {
      //...

      //Catch domain shutdown (Hack: frantically look for things we can catch)
      if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsDefaultAppDomain())
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += MyTerminationHandler;
      else
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += MyTerminationHandler;
   }

   private void MyTerminationHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //The domain is dying. Serialize out our values
      this.Dispose();
   }

   ...
}
```

This has been tested inside a *"web-site"* an a *"WinForms"* application.

The more complete code, showing an implementation of `IDisposable`:

```
class InternalSqm : IDisposable
{
   private Boolean _disposed = false;

   //constructor
   public InternalSqm()
   {
      //...

      //Catch domain shutdown (Hack: frantically look for things we can catch)
      if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsDefaultAppDomain())
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += MyTerminationHandler;
      else
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload += MyTerminationHandler;
   }

   private void MyTerminationHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      //The domain is dying. Serialize out our values
      this.Dispose();
   }
```

.

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Finalizer (Finalizer uses the C++ destructor syntax)
   /// </summary>
   ~InternalSqm()
   {
      Dispose(false); //False: it's not safe to access managed members
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      this.Dispose(true); //True; it is safe to access managed members
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this); //Garbage collector doesn't need to bother to call finalize later
   }

   protected virtual void Dispose(Boolean safeToAccessManagedResources)
   {
      if (_disposed)
         return; //be resilient to double calls to Dispose

      try
      {
         if (safeToAccessManagedResources)
         {
            // Free other state (managed objects).                   
            this.CloseSession(); //save internal stuff to persistent storage
         }
         // Free your own state (unmanaged objects).
         // Set large fields to null. Etc.
      }
      finally
      {
         _disposed = true;
      }
   }
}
```

### Sample usage

From a library that does image processing:

```
public static class GraphicsLibrary
{
    public Image RotateImage(Image image, Double angleInDegrees)
    {
       Sqm.TimerStart("GraphicaLibrary.RotateImage");
       ...
       Sqm.TimerStop("GraphicaLibrary.RotateImage");
    }
}
```

From a helper class that can execute a query

```
public static class DataHelper
{
    public IDataReader ExecuteQuery(IDbConnection conn, String sql)
    {
       Sqm.TimerStart("DataHelper_ExecuteQuery");
       ...
       Sqm.TimerStop("DataHelper_ExecuteQuery");
    }
}
```

For WinForms themed drawing

```
public static class ThemeLib
{
   public void DrawButton(Graphics g, Rectangle r, String text)
   {
      Sqm.AddToAverage("ThemeLib/DrawButton/TextLength", text.Length);
   }
}
```

In a web-site:

```
private void GetUser(HttpSessionState session)
{
   LoginUser user = (LoginUser)session["currentUser"];

   if (user != null)
      Sqm.Increment("GetUser_UserAlreadyFoundInSession", 1);

   ...
}
```

In an extension method

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert the guid to a quoted string
/// </summary>
/// <param name="source">A Guid to convert to a quoted string</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ToQuotedStr(this Guid source)
{
   String s = "'" + source.ToString("B") + "'"; //B=braces format "{6CC82DE0-F45D-4ED1-8FAB-5C23DE0FF64C}"

   //Record how often we dealt with each type of UUID
   Sqm.Increment("String.ToQuotedStr_UUIDType_"+s[16], 1);

   return s;
}
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Comment: This is pretty dangerous, though - if you hit the `ProcessExit` case, and you take more than 2 seconds, your data will be lost. Given that your original example seemed to involve an HTTP post, you're quite likely to run straight into that problem aren't you? Add to that the problem of abnormal termination, and this whole approach looks flaky. I'd be inclined to save data out on an inactivity timeout instead of waiting until it's probably too late. If that means saving slightly more often than might have been necessary, then so be it.

Comment: @IanGriffiths Problem with saving is the rolling file model. So my each time my gui `Contoso.exe` shuts down, a file `Contoso-sqmxx.xml` is written out. Where `XX` rolls up to a maximum (e.g. `Contoso-sqm00.xml` through `Contoso-sqm09.xml`). If `Contoso-sqm00` and `01` and `02` exist, it saves to `03`. If i save every *n* seconds, then i'll quickly roll-over other files.

Comment: That's not necessarily a showstopper. You could just keep replacing the last file - so when you write out data, don't discard it, and next time, just write out a larger file. (For extra robustness, I'd write it to some temp name, like `Contoso-sqm02~.xml`, and then after a successful write, delete `Contoso-sqm02.xml` and rename `Contoso-sqm02~.xml` to `Contoso-sqm02.xml`)

Answer (score 13):

There are two problems here:

- You are insistent that the `List<string>` might have been finalized. `List<string>` doesn't *have* a finalizer, and it *won't* have been garbage collected yet (because you have a reference to it). (Those are different operations.) Your `SQL` finalizer will still see valid data. So actually, a finalizer *might* be okay - although by the time the finalizer runs some *other* resources that you require may have gone away - and the finalizer may not even end up being called. So I think this is simultaneously more feasible than you expect - and a worse idea in general.
- You are insistent that you don't want to make this deterministic by putting it in the control of the developer, whether that's using `IDisposable` or not. This is simply fighting against what .NET provides. The garbage collector is meant to be for *memory* resources; any *non-memory* resources which require deterministic cleanup (including flushing etc) *should* be cleaned up explicitly. You can use a finalizer as a last "best effort" clean-up, but it should not be used in the way you're trying to use it.

There are some approaches that you *could* use to try to work around this, such as using a "canary" object with a reference to the "real" object: keep a strong reference to the object you're interested elsewhere, and have a finalizer *just* in the canary object, so that the *only* thing to be finalized is the canary object - which then triggers the appropriate flushing and removes the last strong reference, leaving the real object eligible for GC - but it's still fundamentally a bad idea, and with static variables in the mix it becomes even worse.

Likewise you *can* use the [`AppDomain.DomainUnload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload.aspx) event - but again, I wouldn't. By the time the domain is being unloaded, I would be worried about the state of the rest of the objects - and it doesn't get called for the default domain.

Basically, I think you should change your design. We don't really know the background of the API you're trying to design, but the way you're going at the moment just won't work. I would try to avoid the static variable, personally - at least for anything which is important in terms of timing. There could still be a single object behind the scenes for coordination, but exposing that in your API feels like a mistake to me. However much you protest about other languages and other platforms, if you're working in .NET you need to accept it is what it is. Fighting against the system is not going to help you in the long term.

The earlier you come to the conclusion that you need to change your API design, the more time you have to think about what that new API should look like.

Comment: If you replace `List<String>` with `List<AnythingElse>` you can watch the child `AnythingElse` objects get finalized before the list itself is finalized. And the list is finalized before my **`Sqm`** class is finalized. The design is that any code anywhere can call `Sqm.AddSample(...)`. If the developer has to construct an instance of the class, hold the reference somewhere, and call something to "shutdown", then they (they being me, or a colleague) just won't use it. So it's this or nothing.

Comment: @IanBoyd: They may be finalized, but they won't be garbage collected. You never said that it was a list of finalizable types (which are pretty rare in my experience - do you often write finalizers?) - you said it was a list of strings. But basically, if it's "this design that fundamentally goes against .NET principles, or nothing" then it sounds like the answer is "nothing" - or you accept a reduced reliability (e.g. flushing every 10 seconds and accepting potential data loss).

Comment: @IanGriffiths: Indeed, it's not useful *in general* - but it may be useful in *some* contexts. (That's why I added a comment asking for details on the context.)

Comment: @JonSkeet yes - sorry, missed the fact that you did in fact mention that the default domain doesn't raise it. Have deleted my comment.

Comment: It's not a list of strings. It's a list of objects that are not mine. If any one of them has a finalizer, then it won't work.

Comment: @IanBoyd: Don't you think it would have been helpful to say that instead of writing a misleading question? Again, I don't think a finalizer is the right approach anyway. (If you *really* want to use a finalizer than a "canary" object to warn about finalization would possibly work, but you'd still be relying on finalization in a way that it was not intended for.)

Answer (score 1):

There's a `ProcessExit` event on the AppDomain you could try to hook, though I don't know much more about it, and it has a default time limit of 2 seconds.

Something like this (if it's suitable for you);

```
class SQM
{

    static Lazy<SQM> _Instance = new Lazy<SQM>( CreateInstance );

    private static SQM CreateInstance()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler( Cleanup );
        return new SQM();
    }

    private static Cleanup()
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to call `Dispose`. If the class that implements `IDisposable` uses only managed resources, then those resources will be released as they naturally would when the program completes. If the class uses un-managed resources, then that class should extend `CriticalFinalizerObject` and free those resources in its finalizer (as well as in its `Dispose` method).

In other words, proper use of the `IDisposable` interface doesn't require that `Dispose` ever be called. It can be called to release managed or un-managed resources at a particular point in the program, but a leak that occurs because of **not** calling it should be considered a bug.

**Edit**

> What is the C# equivalent of *i see myself going away, clean myself up*?

In response to your edited question, I think you're looking for the finalizer:

```
class Foo {
    ~Foo() {
        // Finalizer code. Called when garbage collected, maybe...
    }
}
```

Be aware, though, that there's no guarantee this method will be called. If you absolutely need it called, you should extend `System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution.CriticalFinalizerObject`.

I may still be confused by your question, though. The finalizer is definitely **NOT** the place to "save my internal values to a file."

Comment: *"The finalizer is definitely **NOT** the place to save my internal values to a file"* You're **right**! That's the problem i'm trying to solve!. People have been confusing *"clean myself up"* with *"freeing resources"* and wanting to explain to me how the garbage collector will free resources for me. That's not what i'm asking; i'm not asking how freeing resources - i'm asking about *"cleaning up"*. Doing those things that you have to do before you're destroyed. Yes, the garbage collector will bullzone my house; but i'd like to mail the final cheque to the city before it's destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ken's answer, the answer to "How can I dispose my object?" is, you can't.

The concept you're looking for is a static deconstructor, or a deconstructor that would run when the static methods are being freed. [This does not exist in managed code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182362/static-deconstructor), and in most (all?) cases shouldn't be necessary. You're more than likely looking at your static methods being unloaded when the executable ends, and the OS will clean up everything at that point.

If you absolutely need to free up resources, and this object must be shared between all active instances, you could create a reference counter and dispose of the object when you're sure all references have been released. I would put heavy consideration into whether this is the correct approach for you first. New instances would need to verify whether your object is `null`, and instantiate it again if so.

Comment: i don't want to *"free up resources"*. That was the wrong phrasing. i need to *"shutdown"* my object. In other words, the user calls `Foo.Sqm.AddString("Hello")`. The `Sqm` class needs to save that string to the hard drive. During Garbage Collection is too late to save those strings.

Comment: @IanBoyd You could consider using the finalizer on `Sqm`, but be aware that it doesn't get called in cases where your object was disposed. It'd be better and more reliable to call a `Sqm.Save()` when you need to (shutdown or whenever). Perhaps make `Foo` an `IDisposable` and use reference counting with that.

Comment: The finalizer would not be called if i placed `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`. i *could* choose to *not* call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` in my `Dispose` method. But then the question becomes how do i get someone to call `Dispose` (as i don't want the developer to have to do it)

Answer (score 0):

The [AppDomain Domain Unload Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.domainunload.aspx) seems like it would be a good fit for what you're looking for. Since static variables persist until the AppDomain is unloaded, this should give you a hook in right before the variable is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You're spending all this time fighting the language, why not redesign so that the problem doesn't exist?

e.g. If you need to save the state of a variable, instead of trying to catch it before it is destroyed, save it each time it is modified, and overwrite the previous state.

Comment: Problem with that is that it might take a few dozen milliseconds to write out the state. When the call happens 50,000 times a second, it gets kind of slow.

Answer (score -1):

They will persist for the duration of AppDomain. Changes done to static variable are visible across methods.

MSDN:

If a local variable is declared with the Static keyword, its lifetime is longer than the execution time of the procedure in which it is declared. If the procedure is inside a module, the static variable survives as long as your application continues running.

Comment: "he static variable survives as long as your application continues running". And when the application stops running, the variable will be destroyed. i need to be notified when the application domain is about to end, so i can do required *"stuff"*. (*"Cleanup"* is a word that, while correct, is confusing a lot of people; who confuse it with memory reclamation).